# sc.exe fails with a 1639

Tags: command-line, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

We're setting up a new enviroment and I'm writing batch files to used across multiple machines in a cluster. Consistency is my friend. :)

The command line simply lists the parameters and sets the errorlevel=1639.

```
    d:\services\WFCContainerStatus>sc config ContainerStatusService start=auto
DESCRIPTION:
        Modifies a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
USAGE:
        sc <server> config [service name] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
      A space is required between the equal sign and the value.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec|adapt>
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto>
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>

d:\services\WFCContainerStatus>echo %errorlevel%
1639
```

Looking up the error code has been a trying experience to say the least. Trying net helpmsg was as usefil.

```
d:\services\WFCContainerStatus>net helpmsg 1639

Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
```

I'm sure this is something trivial that I'm doing wrong and that I'm simply not seeing it.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, I need to learn to read because my answer was right there in front of me.

```
d:\services\WFCContainerStatus>sc config ContainerStatusService start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

As the help text said, "A space is required between the equal sign and the value." Add the space and everything works.

Comment: Crazy! Just run into this myself. It seems Windows 10 and Server 2019 (maybe 2016) don't require the space, but Windows 7 does (guessing Server 2008 also). Though these are out of support now but they are still valid for Extended Security Updates for Pro/Enterprise volume users who pay up (until 2023).